# MD5 Comparison not working

Tags: c#, .net, compare, md5

I tried to create a simple little application to make it easier to create the Update files for my main project, by just comparing files in two more or less similar folders and telling me what files are different. But it always gives me the following output when testing two completely similar folders:

> C:\Users\there\Desktop\Folder 2\1.txt
>
> C:\Users\there\Desktop\Folder 2\2.txt

My code:

```
    private void FirstFolderBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
            {
                FirstFolderTB.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
            }
        }
    }

    private void SecondFolderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
            {
                SecondFolderTB.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
            }
        }
    }

    private void CompareBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles(FirstFolderTB.Text))
        {
            byte[] storedFileHash;
            using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
            {
                using (var stream = File.OpenRead(file))
                {
                    storedFileHash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
                }

                using (var stream = File.OpenRead(file.Replace(FirstFolderTB.Text, SecondFolderTB.Text)))
                {
                    if(storedFileHash != md5.ComputeHash(stream))
                    {
                        ResultTB.AppendText(file.Replace(FirstFolderTB.Text, SecondFolderTB.Text) + "\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I think I am just being dumb right now and overseeing some dumb mistake but I would appreciate if someone could help.

Thanks, Jan

Comment: That is an explanation on how to get a MD5 hash, I have a problem doing that. So it is not a duplicate in my oppinion

Comment: Perfect - now this is duplicate of 2 questions that exactly cover all the steps.

Comment: Thats wrong. I didn't know that my problem was the comparison, so I asked what the problem might be. If I knew that it was the comparison I would have looked at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bytes comparison is wrong

> `storedFileHash != md5.ComputeHash(stream)`

this will compare references not the bytes.

Use `SequenceEqual`:

```
if (storedFileHash.SequenceEqual(md5.ComputeHash(stream)) == false) {
    ResultTB.AppendText(file.Replace(FirstFolderTB.Text, SecondFolderTB.Text) + "\n");
}
```

if missing add `using System.Linq` in the using section

Comment: Thanks so much! That fixed my problem. And the mistake was not as dumb as I expected :P